# Is it possible to use `switch_user` through a search field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I'm trying to populate values to use in a search box so that a superuser can [impersonate other users](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html). However, I'm having problems as listed below and I'm not sure if there is a unified solution or at least a 'correct' way to handle it:

1. How to pass the search strings as well as the username values for the script
2. How to reload the current page but supplementing the path with `?_switch_user=jsmith` (for example)
3. If the superuser switches between simulating one user (eg `jsmith`) to another regular user I get an error:

   > You are already switched to "jsmith" user.

**My search form:**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="search" id="search-names" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username to switch to">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**The script:**

This is in my my base twig template (as the form is in the nav bar on all pages). The code I'm actually using is `var searchnames = ["Smith, John",...` but I would somehow need to pass whichever username is selected (eg `jsmith`) to reload the same page but with`?_switch_user=jsmith` as a parameter:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var searchnames = [
    "Smith, John" => "jsmith",
    "Doe, Jane"   => "jdoe1990",
    ];
    $( "#search-names" ).autocomplete({
    source: searchnames
    });
});
</script>
```

My thoughts are to pass a list of all names/usernames from my UserRepository and populate the script with them all in twig. Beyond that though, I don't know where to begin in terms of passing parameters for the `?_switch_user=`

Comment: Which JavaScript library are you using for `.autocomplete`?

Comment: Hi @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels - I'm using `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js` and jQuery (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js`). Is that right? Otherwise I'm happy to change libraries if that's easier

Comment: Neither of them are implement autocomplete. Please check which library defines `jQuery.fn.autocomplete`.

Comment: I've updated my question with all scripts I'm calling in the html - does this help?

Comment: That's not it. I'll just assume you're using [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Ah! Sorry - yes that is where my script from (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). I 'plugged it in' and I've got the search box working with the default `availableTags` they use in their example but not the data I want to populate it with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an associated array in PHP:

```
var searchnames = [
  "Smith, John" => "jsmith",
  "Doe, Jane"   => "jdoe1990",
];
```

In JavaScript, you only have [normal arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). An object can be used for key/value pairs.

The [source option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) can take an array of objects. Each object has a `value` and `label` property.

```
[
  { "label": "Smith, John", "value": "jsmith" },
  { "label": "Doe, Jane", "value": "jdoe1990" }
]
```

If you have a fixed set of users, you can simply add them to your JavaScript function and that's that.

However the users are probably come from a database. You can create an object of all users in the system, pass them to the (Twig) view and output them using the [`json_encode` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html). However this is bad practice as it bloats the HTML and increases security risk. (o.a. All the users are still in the browser cache, even when you log out.)

Instead you probably want to use AJAX. You can set the `source` option to a URL, which is handled by your user controller. (See [the jQuery UI remote example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).)

```
$("#search-names).autocomplete({
  source: "/users/search"
});
```

The search action query the database and create an array with associated arrays each having a `value` and `label` key. Than [output it as JSON](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-response-object).

Last you want to do to load the page when an option is selected. This can be done in JavaScript by setting `window.location`.

```
$("#search-names").autocomplete({
  source: "/users/search",
  change: function() {
    var username = $(this).val();
    if (!username) return;

    window.location = window.location + '?_switch_user=' + username;
  }
});
```

*The code is untested an may require some modifications to make it actually work.*

Comment: Hi @Jasny - Arnold Daniels - thanks for your answer that's a big help. I'm trying to get the AJAX working as you adviced but I think the username for `?_switch_user=` is complicating things. I've updated my question in case you can see what I'm missing?

Comment: @Bendy That's not how Stackoverflow works and makes me sad. If your first question is anwsered, please accept this answer. Than if you have a new question, please post it as a new question. **Do not keep adding questions to your original post!**

Comment: No problem - I was wondering the same to be honest but wasn't sure about continuing conversation in another question..... I have created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602622/how-to-append-a-nested-entity-references-in-order-to-append-to-ajax-script-in-sy