# How to append a nested entity references in order to append to AJAX script in Symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony

This is a follow up question from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568463/is-it-possible-to-use-switch-user-through-a-search-field) if helpful for background information.

I received below I have tried to implement AJAX as suggested. Note: One user(username) can have multiple members associated to it so I need to have to return the relevent username for whichever member is selected:

**Route for response:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/** 
 * @Route("/member/search", name="membersearch")
 */
public function memberSearch(Request $request)
{
    $response = new Response();
    $members = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')->findActiveMembers();
    $response->setContent(json_encode($members));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->send();
}
```

**HTML code:**

I'm assuming my problem (or at least part of it) is the `member_id['username'] but I'm not sure how I can access the username of the associated member

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $( "#search-names" ).autocomplete({
                source: "/member/search",
                minLength: 2,
                change: function() {
                  var familyname = $(this).val();
                  if (!familyname) return;
                  window.location = window.location + '?_switch_user=' + member_id['username'];
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="search-names" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The PHP code doesn't seem correct. You first create the data and than do `$response->setContent($data)` and then `return $response`. Check out [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-response-object) and [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#component-http-foundation-json-response). You should also use the `term` parameter somehow. You can test the PHP side by opening to `/members/search?term=John` in the browser.

Comment: You assume that `$(this).val()` will contain the familyname. However if you make the familyname the `label` and the username the `value` than `$(this).val()` will contain the username. You can try it with a static list with 3 or 4 users first to make sure the JS part works on it's own.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up :) I've was trying `new JsonResponse();` but I've updated to use `->setContent($data)` but PhpStorm is telling me it's not recognised. I'll update the controller code in my question with what I'm using now

Comment: You might want to remove the JavaScript part of this question and add the JSON you would like to have as result. This will attract Symfony devs to answer the question. My Symfony knowledge is pretty basic. It the PHP part is working, it will be pretty easy to get the whole thing to work.

Comment: P.S. I have the feeling, you're not following the guide. I'm pretty sure `$this->render()` doesn't go together with `new Response()`.

Comment: ok thanks very much for the guidance - I'll work on getting the JSON and drop the javascript for now. The `new Response()` is in the guide like that but I've not done JSON before (as you can no doubt tell!) so will go through it all again to check

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels - I have been able to get the autocomplete populating now with a `["familyname1","familyname2","familyname3"] array. However I've been googling the `label`/`value` that you  mentioned in your earlier comment. That looks ideal but I can't see any mention of how I can assign Familyname to label and username to value. Can you offer any guidance?

Comment: Do you realize that $response is not used anyhow? You just create it and do not use.

Comment: Hi @DenisV, thanks - this is my first time with ajax and I'm not sure what exactly I need to be returning(!). I had noticed that since added `$response->send()` (as well as removing `return $this->render(...)`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to make AJAX working. The thing is that you either need two separate actions or one more complicated.

I would recommend creating two separate actions. One will be returning JSON respond (you can either use JsonResponse or manually set the `application/json` `Content-Type`. Don't forget to import JsoneResponse's namespace. The other action would return an array with template vars (don't forget to put @Template() annotation in your controller). Essentially this will be something like this (not tested):

```
/**
 * @Route("/member/search", name="membersearch")
 */
public function memberSearchAction()
{
    $data = array(/*...*/);
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 * @Template()
 */ 
public function indexAction()
{
    return array(/* ... */);
}
```